# Check if UITextField have a leading whitespace

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a TextField called **myTextField**, and I need to check two things:

- If The value is not empty
- If the first letter is not a letter instead of whitespace

For that I try this:

```
if ([myTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]){

//My code

}
```

This check if the textField is empty, but how I can check if the first letter is no a whitespace ?

Comment: Do you intend to remove the leading whitespace or are you expecting it to be present?

Comment: expecting it to be present, but if you tell me how I can remove the leading whitespace is good too! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check that there is no whitespace and to check that it is **NOT** empty try the below, note the `!` is basically saying `if((myTextField is not empty) && (myTextField does not have a prefix of " "))`

```
if(![myTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] && ![myTextField.text hasPrefix:@" "]) {
    // Do whatever you want
} else if(![myTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] && [myTextField.text hasPrefix:@" "]) {
    // Do whatever we want to remove whitespace, you can use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` to remove white space   
} else {
    // Else do what you want if nothing else matches.
}
```